# Anyway to rsync gsutil files after a certain timestamp?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, rsync, gsutil

I am wondering if there is a way to `rsync` files from a local computer to a GCS bucket, but only the files that have a created or modified timestamp after a given timestamp.

This `rsync` command will run periodically to sync the files from the local computer to the bucket. I would eventually want to delete these files from the bucket, but if the `rsync` command ran again, I assume that the files that were deleted would get re-added to the bucket. I would only want to sync the files that were added or modified after the timestamp of the last `rsync` run.

For example, let's say my `rsync` command runs at the start of the new day (12:00 am)

I have file `file.txt` and I ran my `rsync` command runs. My bucket should now have `file.txt`.

I delete `file.txt` from my bucket before the next time it runs and added a new file called `newfile.txt`. When the `rsync` command runs the next time, I would only want `newfile.txt` to be in the bucket since this is a new file since the last time `rsync` was ran and no changes have been made to `file.txt`.

Is it possible to do this? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: hi, I am sure there will be other ways to do this but I was wondering if its possible for you to delete the files that are not needed from the source directory itself? In that case you can use "gsutil rsync -d " command which will Delete extra files under dst_url not found under src_url.  In this case you need not write a code to delete the files from bucket. There are risk involved and should be only used when you are sure that bucket will only have files which you will have in local and there will not be a scenario where you have files in bucket which are not in local.

Comment: Im not sure if you have already checked "gsutil help rsync " to see of there are any more options

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding there is no such way to do the thing you are looking for using `gsutil rsync`. Also [this document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync#options) doesn’t provide any such option to do the same. You may consider deleting the files which you don’t need in the destination directory after running the rsync command.